# shouldSelect method of UITabBarControllerDelegate never invoked

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am using Swift 4 and XCode 9. I am trying to programmatically control navigation in my UITabBarController. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html), I need to implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol. However, the method I implemented never get called:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
            shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        print("Should go here...")
        return true
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect there's some typographic error that makes your method not match up with the delegate method it's meant to override, but I can't find the difference

Comment: @Alexander All the methods in the delegate are optional, so no `override` keyword required. The issue was answered correctly, I was not properly initializing the controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the wrong delegate. Update `viewDidLoad` to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self // or just "delegate = self"
}
```

The idea is that you want this tab controller to be its own delegate.

Comment: Why bother with that at all. As far as I know he can just remove UITabBarControllerDelegate from the declaration

Comment: @LeoDabus Not if he wants the tab controller to dictate whether a given tab can be selected or not.

Comment: `UITabBarController` doesn't implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini just saw that it conforms to `UITabBarDelegate` not `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

Comment: @rmaddy Out of sheer curiosity, what exactly am I accessing when doing `tabBarController?`... what is injected there?

Comment: `UIViewController` provides the `tabBarController` property as a convenience so any view controller embedded in a tab bar controller can its parent tab bar controller. Since `UITabBarController` extends `UIViewController` is also has this property. In fact, if you embed a tab controller inside another tab controller, the child tab controller can use its `tabBarController` property to get the parent tab controller. In your case You are subclassing `UITabBarController` and you want to access `self`, not any parent tab controller.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the item selected event, you have to override **didSelect** method.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("Should go here...")
}
```

Comment: This is called AFTER the new UIView is displayed. The OP wants to make the shouldSelect method get called so he can do something BEFORE the new UIView is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The right method to implement is DidSelect.....